# Getting an error for a simple Tkinter program

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been trying to make a simple program using Tkinter and Python. All you do is click buttons and depending on what button you click, it updates certain labels. This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

apples = 0
gold = 0

def pick():
    global apples
    apples = apples + 1


def sell():
    global apples
    global gold
    gold = gold + (apples * 10)
    apples = 0

app = Tk()

app.title("Apple Picking Simulator 2014")
app.geometry("400x300+100+60")

label1 = Label(text = "Welcome to Apple Picking Simulator 2014!").pack()
Label().pack()
label2 = Label(text = "Apples: " + apples).pack()
label3 = Label(text = "Gold: " + gold).pack()
button1 = Button(text = "Pick Apple", command = pick).pack()
button2 = Button(text = "Sell Apples", command = sell).pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Now, whenever I try to run the program, I just get the error:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

I understand that it can't convert an integer to a string, but I've been trying everything, and I can't seem to make it work. Is there an easy way to display the apple and gold numbers on the window and have them update every time I click the pick or sell button? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to concatenate an integer to a string is what is causing your error. You need to explicitly cast your `apples` and `gold` integer variables to a string using the [`str` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str).

Replace:

```
label2 = Label(text = "Apples: " + apples).pack()
label3 = Label(text = "Gold: " + gold).pack()
```

With:

```
label2 = Label(text = "Apples: " + str(apples)).pack()
label3 = Label(text = "Gold: " + str(gold)).pack()
```

Fixed source code:

```
from tkinter import *

apples = 0
gold = 0

def pick():
    global apples
    apples = apples + 1


def sell():
    global apples
    global gold
    gold = gold + (apples * 10)
    apples = 0

app = Tk()

app.title("Apple Picking Simulator 2014")
app.geometry("400x300+100+60")

label1 = Label(text = "Welcome to Apple Picking Simulator 2014!").pack()
Label().pack()
label2 = Label(text = "Apples: " + str(apples)).pack()
label3 = Label(text = "Gold: " + str(gold)).pack()
button1 = Button(text = "Pick Apple", command = pick).pack()
button2 = Button(text = "Sell Apples", command = sell).pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. This did get rid of the error. I thought I did this before. But, there still is a problem. Every time I click a button, it doesn't update the label with the new amount of apples or gold. Any way to make this happen? Or can that not work?

Comment: @Hero2016 I'm not sure how to help you there, but you probably need to add some code to change the label in your `pick` and `sell` callbacks. You could post a new question about this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to concatenate a string and an integer:

```
label2 = Label(text = "Apples: " + apples).pack()
label3 = Label(text = "Gold: " + gold).pack()
```

This produces an error:

```
>>> apples = 0
>>> "Apples: ", apples
('Apples: ', 0)
>>> "Apples: " + apples
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
>>>
```

Here is your edited code:

```
from tkinter import *

apples = 0
gold = 0

def pick():
    global apples
    apples = apples + 1


def sell():
    global apples
    global gold
    gold = gold + (apples * 10)
    apples = 0

app = Tk()

app.title("Apple Picking Simulator 2014")
app.geometry("400x300+100+60")

label1 = Label(text = "Welcome to Apple Picking Simulator 2014!").pack()
Label().pack()
label2 = Label(text = "Apples: " + str(apples)).pack()
label3 = Label(text = "Gold: " + str(gold)).pack()
button1 = Button(text = "Pick Apple", command = pick).pack()
button2 = Button(text = "Sell Apples", command = sell).pack()

app.mainloop()
```